# Locked out of account because of keyboard language mac

Tags: mac, keyboard, login

I just bough a new macbook air with yosemite installed. After a week, the keyboard started switching to weird symbols. I restarted and it went back to English, so I could log in with my user password. But then it happened again. I restarted, and now I cannot log in because I suspect the keyboard is still inputting strange symbols. Please can anyone help? I am not super savvy, but also not a novice.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you aren't pressing the key for too long and that you don't have any modifier keys like alt, function, Mac key, etc pressed while typing. Also, check to see if you can look at your accessibility options prior to logging in. You might have a setting turned on there that's modifying your keys unwantedly.